# How to set the same type for multiple glossary entries?

Tags: glossaries

I'm using the `glossaries` package with two glossaries, one for general definitions and one for math notation. It seems that for every entry of the notation glossary, I have to seperately type `type=notation` in the options. Instead of

```
\newglossaryentry{letter:A}{
    type=notation,
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}}},
    description={This is the letter A.},
}
\newglossaryentry{letter:B}{
    type=notation,
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{B}}},
    description={This is the letter A.},
}
\newglossaryentry{letter:C}{
    type=notation,
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{C}}},
    description={This is the letter C.},
}
...
```

I'd much rather have a more compact solution like `\setglossarytype{notation}` so I can write

```
\setglossarytype{notation}
\newglossaryentry{letter:A}{
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}}},
    description={This is the letter A.},
}
\newglossaryentry{letter:B}{
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{B}}},
    description={This is the letter A.},
}
\newglossaryentry{letter:C}{
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{C}}},
    description={This is the letter C.},
}
...
```

instead. Is this somehow doable?

Full MWE, if necessary:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{letter:A}{
    type=notation,
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}}},
    description={This is the letter A.},
}
\newglossaryentry{letter:B}{
    type=notation,
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{B}}},
    description={This is the letter A.},
}
\newglossaryentry{letter:C}{
    type=notation,
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{C}}},
    description={This is the letter C.},
}

\begin{document}
\gls{letter:A} comes before \gls{letter:B}, and then \gls{letter:C} at the end.
\printglossary[type=notation]
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can introduce a \newcommand the way you like it, e.g.:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{glossaries}
\newglossary[nlg]{notation}{not}{ntn}{Notation}

\newcommand\nge[1]{ % <<< -----------------
  \newglossaryentry{letter:#1}{
    type=notation,
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{#1}}},
    description={This is the letter #1.},
  }
}

\makeglossaries
\newglossaryentry{letter:A}{
    type=notation,
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{A}}},
    description={This is the letter A.},
}
\newglossaryentry{letter:B}{
    type=notation,
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{B}}},
    description={This is the letter A.},
}
\newglossaryentry{letter:C}{
    type=notation,
    name={\ensuremath{\mathcal{C}}},
    description={This is the letter C.},
}
\nge{D} % <<< -----------------

\nge{E} % <<< -----------------

\begin{document}
\gls{letter:A} comes before \gls{letter:B}, and then \gls{letter:C} at the end.


What's about \gls{letter:E} and \gls{letter:D}?

\printglossary[type=notation]
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice, didn't think of a new command as an option. I need it to be more general, but this shows the angle of attack and I can easily modify it according to my needs.